How to masking sensitive data in datadog
As far as I know, datadog will collect all the data including PII (Personally identifiable information) data. 
So is there any approach that I can use to prevent them from collecting it? such as masking those PII data before datadog collecting them.
I've researched the docs but can't find anything.
Please help, thanks.

The feature you are looking for is Sensitive Data Scanner. There are several ways to configure this feature. Once you have it enable, you can add custom rules and select from a library of rules to redact information from logs, APM traces, events, and RUM data.
